# GWT d3 Server call block transition

Tags: java, gwt, d3.js

I'm using GWT in my application to retreive data from the server. Since this will take a while my idea was to use the visualization system based on d3 to show a nice loading animation

Here's an example showing the situation

```
 btnShow.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        .....
                        .....
                        //calls native javascript that will setup the needed transisitons using d3s native select().transition() system
                        showWaitingAnimation(visualizationHTMLPlane)
                        //calls my gwt server side
                        server.getPoints(callBack);
             }
 }
```

Since the GWT call is asynchrnonous I figured creating an animation would be possible however the transition gets only executed if i remove the server call in GWT.

Does anybody know why this happens and what would be the solution to this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. What currently happens that you don't want to happen and what is the code that effects this? The general pattern is that you would enable the loading screen when starting the asynchronous call and disable it in the handler for the returned data.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. What I want is the following 1. User clicks button 2. click handler is called 3. a waiting animation is started using the (existing) function showWaitingAnimation. 4. The server call is made by calling server.getPoints 5. Once the server call finishes the callback (callBack.onSuccess or callBack.onFailure) method will end the animation using a function endWaitingAnimation.  Currently the animation will only run if I remove the  server.getPoints call from the code above. Hope it is now clearer

Comment: Hmm, weird. I think we would need to see the complete code to figure this one out.